# Wildfly started, but is showing as lazy services & applications are not working

Tags: deployment, wildfly, wildfly-11

Using Wildfly 11, on windows OS 12.

Upon starting wildfly, below is displayed

**WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 2993ms - Started 103 of 113 services (31 services are lazy, passive or on-demand**)

My wildfly deployments has 5 war files, none of which are starting/running/working now.

Can you pls help as to why this is happening & what is the solution for the same

Comment: From the log that looks like WildFly 10 not 11 and what do you mean by "starting/running/working"?

Comment: Is expected that the server will only start the services that are needed by your apps. What happens when you deploy your app?